# How to define Log4j2 appender logging specific named logger only?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

`private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(ABC.class);
private static final Logger resultLog = LogManager.getLogger("ResultLog");`

How can we define a appender that would only logs specific to "ResultLog" logger?

My current Log4j2.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="ABC" packages="">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/ABC.log"
                     filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/ABC-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d [%t] %p %c{1.} %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
        <File name="resultFile" fileName="logs/result.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n"/>
        </File>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d [%t] %p %c{1.} %m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="resultFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add

```
<Logger name="ResultLog">
  <AppenderRef ...>
</Logger>
```

to the Loggers tag.

You can refer to this manual: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#XML